# Why compiler and run-time assuming the string return type as dynamic?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

In C# 5 and VS 2017, I have,

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
// why json is dynamic here
```

Clearly, SerializeObject returns string then why json is dynamic type instead of string. Yes items is dynamic type.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Clearly, SerializeObject returns string then why json is dynamic type instead of string.

Almost *every* operation involving a `dynamic` value is considered to be dynamic in turn. This includes method calls and most operators. The only exceptions are:

- Constructor calls (so the compile-time type of `new Foo(someDynamicValue)` is still `Foo`)
- The `is` operator (so the compile-time type of `someDynamicValue is Foo` is still `bool`)
- The `as` operator (so the compile-time type of `someDynamicValue as Foo` is still `Foo`)
- Cast expressions (so the compile-time type of `(Foo) someDynamicValue` is still `Foo`)

If you want the type of `json` to be `string`, just declare that explicitly:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
```

Note that the overload of `SerializeObject` that's called will depend on the execution-time type of `items` - unlike with a statically-bound call, even overload resolution happens at execution time when any arguments are dynamic.

Of course, if you know you want to call the `object` overload, you could cast `items` instead:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object) items);
```

Now the call is statically bound, and the compiler knows the return type is `string`.

Comment: You might want to fix the exception list `as` operator, the example in it uses `is` keyword instead of `as`.